# info about MySQL Shell

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, mysql-x-devapi, mysql-shell

I'm using the MySQL shell for the first time.
I ran the following commands:

```
    \connect --mysql root@localhost:3306
    \use myschema
```

But, when I try to follow this instruction:

```
    myColl = db.createCollection('my_coll')
```

I get the error:

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'createCollection' of null
```

The error obviously is due to the fact that `db` object is null, but I don't know the syntax to instantiate it.

Comment: Is the `db` part in something else other than the `mysql>` shell? Is that Python?

Comment: You can only issue mysql commands from mysql shell and myColl = db.createCollection('my_coll') isn't a sql statement..and that error is not a mysql error. so what do you mean by mysql shell?

Comment: I access the mysql shell via the *mysqlsh* command

Comment: @P.Salmon [MySQL Shell](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en//)

Comment: I can run the command without any issue. Are you sure 1. your server supports the mysqlx protocol? (>=8.0 I think?) 2. you have started a mysqlx session? (use `mysqlx://xxxx` URI or `--sqlx`

Answer (score 1):

Commands like `createCollection()` are part of the X DevAPI which is a client-side interface for the MySQL X Protocol. You are using `--mysql` which creates a connection to the server using the MySQL Classic Protocol, which only supports SQL. To create an X Protocol connection, and assuming the [X Plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/x-plugin.html) is enabled in the default server port, you should use `--mysqlx` instead:

```
\connect --mysqlx root@localhost:33060
```

Disclaimer: I'm the lead developer of the MySQL X DevAPI Connector for Node.js